# Google Play Console: How to promote Android app from Alpha to Beta

Tags: android, apk, release-management, google-play-console, app-distribution

Within our company we have someone that handles the upload and release of our Android apps to the Google Play Console. He told me that there previously was an option to promote an app from Alpha to Beta. As seen in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRhn_8CteK0&t=60) there actually was an option.

However we currently don't see a way to move the Alpha app to Beta. There is only an option to promote the app to production.

Is it still possible to promote the Android app from Alpha to Beta? Or should we upload the same app to Beta again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue for one of our apps. It seems that Google limited the process so you can't move an app from the `closed alpha track` to the `closed beta track` (or any other closed track). This is probably due to the fact that Google wants to promote open beta testing. Once I changed my closed beta track to an `open beta track` the button reappeared.

**Note that once you set the track to open you can't change it back to closed, so you'll have to be sure that this is what you want.**

To move the beta track from closed to open:

1. click on the **manage** button next to the beta track.
2. open up the **manage testers** panel.
3. select the **open beta testing** option next to **choose a testing method**

[image]

Comment: how much time is it going to take the console to shift an app from closed alpha to open beta?

Comment: @abbujan I don't remember, I think changing tracks happens instantaneous.

Answer (score 20):

I have tried to use this option weeks ago. but I didn't find it, I have made some research about this and it sounds to be removed. to create beta release just go to the beta version and click on create a beta release and click choose from the library, choose the APK in the alpha channel then publish it

Comment: Thanks, thats probably the way to do it now

Comment: Did you find a reason why it has been removed? This really feels like a downgrade :-(

Comment: I think they work around it by allowing you to choose the APK type for you library when you uploading beta or production @JasperdeVries

Answer (score 0):

Now this option available Go Alpha-> Manage

[image]

Comment: Strangely I still only have one option 'RELEASE TO PRODUCTION'. Maybe the functionality is rolled out gradually or I need to upload a new version. I will check it out when we want to upload a new version.

Comment: I think that I've found the cause and the solution. Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62002149/2212770. Can you confirm that you are using an open beta track?

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a new app and had this issue.  The solution was to:

1. Have the app reviewed by Google. It seems you can't do an open test before then.
2. Go to the "open testing" tab and click "unpause track".  For some reason, the beta track is "paused" by default.